# How could get text data from PDF file with next.js API routes

Tags: javascript, pdf, next.js, routes

I'm try to extract text data from a URL which contain a PDF download link in Next.js API routes.

Here is my code:
[API]

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { PDFExtract, PDFExtractOptions } from "pdf.js-extract";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    
    try {

        const url = await request.json();

        const pdfExtract = new PDFExtract();
        const options: PDFExtractOptions = {};

        const data = await pdfExtract.extract(url, options);

        return NextResponse.json({ message: data.filename});

    } catch (error) {

        console.error(error);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: "An error occurred while processing the PDF" }, { status: 500 });

    }
}
```

[client side]:

```
// call api

  try {
    const res = await fetch("/api/pdf_language_detector", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ url }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {

  }
```

[Example output from pdf.js-extract]

```json
{
  "filename": "helloworld.pdf",
  "meta": {
    "info": {
      "PDFFormatVersion": "1.7",
      "IsAcroFormPresent": false,
      "IsCollectionPresent": false,
      "IsLinearized": true,
      "IsXFAPresent": false
    },
    "metadata": {
      "dc:format": "application/pdf",
      "dc:creator": "someone",
      "dc:title": "This is a hello world PDF file",
      "xmp:createdate": "2000-06-29T10:21:08+11:00",
      "xmp:creatortool": "Microsoft Word 8.0",
      "xmp:modifydate": "2013-10-28T15:24:13-04:00",
      "xmp:metadatadate": "2013-10-28T15:24:13-04:00",
      "pdf:producer": "Acrobat Distiller 4.0 for Windows",
      "xmpmm:documentid": "uuid:0205e221-80a8-459e-a522-635ed5c1e2e6",
      "xmpmm:instanceid": "uuid:68d6ae6d-43c4-472d-9b28-7c4add8f9e46"
    }
  },
  "pages": [
    {
      "pageInfo": {
        "num": 1,
        "scale": 1,
        "rotation": 0,
        "offsetX": 0,
        "offsetY": 0,
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
      },
      "links": [
        "https://github.com"
      ],
      "content": [
        {
          "x": 70,
          "y": 150,
          "str": "Hello, world!",
          "dir": "ltr",
          "width": 64.656,
          "height": 12,
          "fontName": "Times"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pdfInfo": {
    "numPages": 1,
    "fingerprint": "1ee9219eb9eaa49acbfc20155ac359c3"
  }
}
```

I have been try to convert `data.filename` to `String(data.filename)`, but I got same error:

> (An error occurred while processing the PDF)

How could I solve this?

Comment: what does this `console.error(error)` print out on the terminal

Comment: I got this ```Object { error: {…} }
​
error: Object { code: "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE" }
​​
code: "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
```

Comment: It says “invalid arg”. You are passing wrong arguments to ‘pdfExtract.extract’. ‘console.log(url)’ check what url is printing on the console.